# Broken Pipe signal on a DNS client

Tags: process, dns, udp, pipe, fork

I'm building a DNS client. A child process handles the request through an UDP socket, while the parent handles the reply. I need the parent to know how many bytes were sent, in order to print the URLs. I tried the following approach with pipe()

```
childPID = fork();
pipe(fd);

if(childPID == 0){
    close(fd[0]);

    sent_bytes = sendDNS(sock_udp, &serverAddr, argv[2]);

    memcpy(in_buf, &sent_bytes, sizeof(sent_bytes));

    write(fd[1], in_buf, sizeof(sent_bytes));
    exit(0);

}
else{
    close(fd[1]);

    int inBytes = -1;
    struct sockaddr reply_addr;

    n = sizeof(reply_addr);

    while(inBytes < 0){
        inBytes = recvfrom(sock_udp, buffer, DNS_MAX_RESPONSE, 0, &reply_addr, (socklen_t*)&n);

        read(fd[0], out_buf, sizeof(sent_bytes));
        memcpy(pipe_msg, out_buf, sizeof(sent_bytes));

        printDNSmsg((struct dnsReply*)buffer);

    }
}
```

But GDB shows a SIGPIPE received on the child process. What am I missing?

---

How would you print a DNS reply (variable length buffer)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pipe()` *before* `fork()`, of course. But you're not actually using the information anywhere. Why do you care how many bytes were sent, as long as you got a reply? And why would you do a UDP send in a separate thread, let alone a separate process? It all seems completely pointless.